# Disabling a button in Visualforce salesforce

Tags: visualforce, button

I have a " next " button in my page defined as follows inside a html table

```
<td colspan="1" class="blue lighten-5 blue-text text-darken-1 " >
    <h4> <span>
                <input id="next" type="button" name="next" onclick="next();" value="Next"  />
    </span></h4>
</td>
```

Action function:

```
<!-- displays the next set of cases in pagination -->
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!next}" name="next"  reRender="List">        
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Controller method:

```
public Boolean getDisableNext(){

        if((counter + limitSize) >= totalSize )
            return true ;
        else
            return false ;
    }
```

My question is how can I disable the button by the value of the disablenext. The next function which i am calling from the action function is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can used html disabled attribute.

```
<td colspan="1" class="blue lighten-5 blue-text text-darken-1 " >
    <h4> 
        <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelTrue" rendered="{!yourtrueCondition"}>
             <input id="next" type="button" name="next" onclick="next();" value="Next" disabled /></apex:outputPanel>

        <apex:outputPanel id="thePanelFalse" rendered="{!yourFalseCondition"}>
             <input id="next" type="button" name="next" onclick="next();" value="Next" /></apex:outputPanel>


    </h4>
</td>
```